# Unable to use blktrace

Tags: linux, blktrace

Trying to run below command:
`blktrace -d /dev/sda -o -|blkparse -i -`
Below error is seen:

```
BLKTRACESETUP(2) /dev/sda failed: 25/Inappropriate ioctl for device
Thread 0 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace0: 2/No such file or directory
Thread 1 failed open /sys/kernel/debug/block/(null)/trace1: 2/No such file or directory
FAILED to start thread on CPU 0: 1/Operation not permitted
FAILED to start thread on CPU 1: 1/Operation not permitted
```

Enabled 'CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE=y' already. What is the cause for this error, how to resolve, any input will help.

Comment: This would be better asked on the Unix & Linux exchange.